# HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class jav.com.controller.conrollerServletLogin

Tags: java, servlets

I am developing a simple login form but got error while running one Tomcat server.

Below is the stack trace :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
at jav.com.utility.Utility.getConnection(Utility.java:23)
at jav.com.dao.daoLogin.<init>(daoLogin.java:12)
at jav.com.controller.conrollerServletLogin.<init>(conrollerServletLogin.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

db.properties file

```
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pra
user=root
password=root
```

Utility.java

```
package jav.com.utility;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;


public class Utility {
 private static Connection connection;
 public static Connection getConnection() {
  if (connection != null) {
   return connection;
  } else {
   try {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    // file input output this code read db.properties file from     location src
    InputStream inputStream = Utility.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");
    prop.load(inputStream);
    // String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String driver = prop.getProperty("driver");
    String url = prop.getProperty("url");
    String user = prop.getProperty("user");
    String password = prop.getProperty("password");
    Class.forName(driver);
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {


    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (SQLException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I tried to solve but I am getting error like 404 and 500 .

Comment: Stack trace clearly suggests that something is wrong with `Utility` class reading properties file.

Comment: It is showing me error in Utility.java line 23 which is 
     prop.load(inputStream);
it's syntax is right but also it is showing me error I don't know what is the problem. Can you help me with this ? 
thank you Abubakkar

Comment: Try `getResourceAsStream("db.properties")` instead of `getResourceAsStream("/db.properties")` .And make sure "db.properties" file is in classpath.

Comment: It also did not help. 
I wanted to share my project with you if you provide me some of your link to share so that you could help me .

Comment: Have you checked that "db.properties" is in classpath? You can put a screenshot of your project structure.

Comment: Thank you Abubakkar I solved it 
I had not imported sql jar in the project.